# Hive query - FAILED SemanticException invalid path

Tags: csv, azure, hadoop, hive

**Here is my problem:**

I have just gotten my initial Azure subscription converted to a Pay-As-You-Go subscription (first was a 30-day trial) after it was shut down when I used up the first set of free credits. Now all is working fine again - I  still have the same old resource group under which I establish a new cluster. The files with my CSV-data are all still present in the container I created last time (not the default container but one that was established earlier). The only thing I had to recreate was the Hive table needed to load the data into. Also that table I was able to establish again. However when I then try to run a Hive query to actually load data into the Hive table from the CSV-file as follows...

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/container1/HdiSamples/user/data-file.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE default.hive_table;
```

...I am constantly receiving "Failed" as an error message (I use Data Lake tools for VS to upload blobs and run the queries). In the specificerror log the line beginning with 'FAILED: SemanticException etc.' stands out each time... (this despite of using different locations for the file upload).

*16/12/01 04:16:25 WARN conf.HiveConf: HiveConf of name hive.log.dir does not exist
FAILED: SemanticException Line 1:17 Invalid path ''/container1/HdiSamples/user/data-file.csv'': No files matching path wasb://container1@resourcegroup.blob.core.windows.net/container1/HdiSamples/user/data-file.csv*

**Here is my question:**

Can anyone tell me why it doesn't find and load the file at/from the location where the file actually resides...?

I just don't get the cause for this error...

Answer (score 2):

Although it's been a while since I asked this question, I worked out a solution to the issue myself which I thought, I'd share with others...

I had problems for about a week, being unable to load data into the Hive tables from the Azure Blob Storage. I had two CSV-files called data-file.csv and data-file-extended-1.CSV in my blob. Please note the capitals in the file extension here!

Hive and Hadoop do NOT accept these files unless...
a) the filename is spelled *exactly* the same way including the capitals in the file-extension
AND
b) the filename is shortened drastically and without the hyphens and numbers (in my case I used only 6 conjoined letters, i.e. "datfil" and "datfix")

Shockingly, there isn't any mention of these issues in neither the official Azure documentation nor did I find anything on the web. However, these two adjustments will resolve the error message.

Just to let people know...